# Who should be responsible for the release the setter's parameter?

Tags: objective-c, setter

Please see code as follow:

```
- (void) setSomeThing:(NSString *) someThingNew
{
     if(someThing!=someThingNew)
     {
         [someThingNew retain];
         [someThing release];
         someThing = someThingNew;
     }
 }

 ... ...
 - (void) dealloc
 {
     [someThing release];
     [super dealloc];
 }
@end
```

The parameter of setter `someThingNew` has been `retain` in the setter method, which means its retain count is 1.

Here the question:is the `someThingNew` should `release`?

Or because `someThing` and `someThingNew` point to the same object, and in the `dealloc` method `someThing` has been `release` so `someThingNew` point to `nil` ?

Comment: Objective C memory management guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the someThingNew should release?

Nope, because now `someThing` and `someThingNew` point to the same address.  By releasing `someThing` in dealloc (and nil'ing it out to be safe, but that's for another question), you balance the retain in the setter.  Everything works out fine!*

<sub>*sidenote: Instances of `NSString` are usually `copy`'d, not `retain`d, in setters so it doesn't matter if you accidentally pass `NSMutableString` to it.</sub>

Comment: My apologies, I accidentally typed an 'r' instead of a period.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your setter method is called someThingNew is retained and someThing is released. Then new address of someThingNew is stored in someThing, making the retain count to 1.

This stays for the class until the object itself is not deallocated. Once dealloc is called the pointer of someThingNew is released, making the retain count to 0.

Comment: So that means [someThing release] actually release someThing and someThingNew. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct: the setter should retain the object if you want to make it a "strong" variable. But you don't have to release it: it's not area of responsibility of the setter. So in the code from where you call the setter you will:

- Allocate the object to be assigned;
- Call the setter;
- Release it when you don't need it anymore.

You're doing it fine, except for the fact that strings are usually copied because since polymorphism is valid, the pointer may point a mutable string object, thus it may change from a moment to another.

**Example:**

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
NSString* newString= [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString: @"Hello"]; // Retain count 1.
[newString autorelease]; // Still 1 as retain count, but it will be decreased
                         // when the pool will be drained.
[object setSomeThing: newString];  // Retain count 2.
[pool drain]; // Retain count 1
```

In this example you clearly see why you need to copy the object instead of retaining it: it's a mutable string so it could be modified at any time.

**Copying the object**

If you copy the object, then the way of how you call the method (so the above code) doesn't change, it will just change the method implementation. Something like this:

```
- (void) setSomeThing:(NSString *) someThingNew
{
     if(someThing!=someThingNew)
     {
         [someThing release];   // Retain count decreased by 1.
         someThing = [someThingNew copy];  // Retain count 1.
     }
 }

 ... ...
 - (void) dealloc
 {
     [someThing release];
     [super dealloc];
 }
@end
```

Comment: In very frist place I gonna ask two question the first is this, the second is the different between retain and copy. You just answer them together. I'm really wanna vote up your answer but I have not enough reputation. Thanks for you work.

Comment: Copy creates a different object, with it's own retain count. When you create a new object it has a retain count of 1. The copied object of course will be in a different area of memory than the original one. I've added an example.

Comment: Thank! Here is the question: you didn't release the someThingNew in the dealloc method, do you mean someThingNew should release in somewhere else?

Comment: In dealloc someThingNew does not exist anymore. Who created it and called the setter should release it.